# Telerik Radgrid dynamically added controls disappear after postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have the feeling this is a rookie problem, but I must be missing something.

I have a **Telerik Radgrid**. In one of the columns I add some controls, during the `ItemDataBound` event. These controls function as checkboxes of sort, so I change some properties using Javascript when people click them.

When it comes to saving everything, the user clicks a button, which causes a postback. 
Now, after the postback, my dynamically created controls are gone. 
How can I retrieve their values to save them?

Cheers,
CJ

**Edit:**

In the ItemCreated event I have this:

```
If (TypeOf (e.Item) Is GridDataItem) Then
Dim dataItem As GridDataItem = CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)
Dim diCell As TableCell = dataItem("Periode")

Dim tbl As Table = CType(diCell.FindControl("tblPeriode"), Table)

Dim cell As TableCell
Dim sdsPerioden As New SqlDataSource()
sdsPerioden.ConnectionString = cs
sdsPerioden.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
sdsPerioden.SelectCommand = "OPLEIDING_PERIODE_JAAR_SELECT_BY_OPLEIDING_ID"
sdsPerioden.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("INT_OPLEIDING_ID", DbType.Int32, Session("OPLEIDING_ID")))
Dim dv As DataView = CType(sdsPerioden.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)

Dim iJaar As Integer = 0
sJaren = New List(Of String)

For Each row As DataRow In dv.Table.Rows
    cell = New TableCell()
    cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    cell.Style("margin-right") = "5px"
    cell.Style("padding") = "0px"
    cell.Width = Unit.Pixel((row("PERIODEN_PER_JAAR") * (15 + 2)) + ((row("PERIODEN_PER_JAAR") / 2) * 3) + 1)
    For i As Integer = 1 To row("PERIODEN_PER_JAAR")
        Dim div As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
        dv.ID = "div" + iJaar.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") + iPeriode.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0")
        dv.Style.Add("height", "15px")
        dv.Style.Add("width", "15px")
        dv.Style.Add("display", "inline-block")
        dv.Style.Add("border-style", "solid")
        dv.Style.Add("border-width", "1px")
        dv.Style.Add("border-color", sKleur)
        dv.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")
        dv.Attributes("IS_CHECKED") = "0"
        dv.Attributes("class") = "periodeCheck"
        cell.Controls.Add(div)
    Next
    tbl.Rows(0).Cells.Add(cell)
Next
End If
```

The Javascript that responds to clicks on the divs:

```
$(".periodeCheck").click(function () {               
    if ($(this).attr('IS_CHECKED') == "0")
    {
        var color = $(this).css('border-left-color');
        $(this).attr('IS_CHECKED', '1');            
        $(this).css('border-style', 'none');
        $(this).css('background-color', color);                     
    }
    else
    {
        var color = $(this).css('background-color');
        $(this).attr('IS_CHECKED', '0');
        $(this).css('border-style', 'solid');
        $(this).css('border-width', '1px');
        $(this).css('border-color', color);
        $(this).css('background-color', "#FFFFFF");

    }
    return false;
});
```

Now when I click on my Save button, I notice that the ItemCreated event fires first, then the Button_Click event. 
In the Button_Click Event I have this:

```
For i = 0 To rgOpleidingLeeritem.MasterTableView.Items.Count - 1
    Dim tbl As Table = CType(rgOpleidingLeeritem.MasterTableView.Items(i).FindControl("tblPeriode"), Table)
    Dim div As HtmlGenericControl
    For Each cell As TableCell In tbl.Rows(0).Cells
        For Each ctl As Control In cell.Controls
            div = CType(ctl, HtmlGenericControl)
            If (div.Attributes("IS_CHECKED") = "1") Then
                'Do something
            End If          
        Next
    Next
Next
```

The 'Do something part is never reached, no matter how many divs I 'check' 
According to the element inspector the divs do have the property 'IS_CHECKED' set to '1' after being clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ItemDataBound, create and add your dynamic controls inside `ItemCreated` event. Don't forget to set the controls' ID.

To access the controls, just use the regular `griddataitem.FindControl(id)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately on ItemCreated I seem to be unable to access the row's data. (apparently this comes available in ItemDataBound) And I need some of this data (like ID's) to create the controls

Comment: you can still set the controls value, etc during itemdatabound. perhaps you should give details on what exactly you are trying to do during the itemdatabound event.

Comment: After changing my code I now create the controls on ItemCreated.
Unfortunately, when clicking the Save button, ItemCreated is fired before the button_click event, so my controls have been recreated (and lost their values) before I can save them.
Can I get the old values back from the viewstate?

Comment: you should be able to read the controls value on postback. I can't help you without having a clue on what's inside your itemdatabound, itemcreate, button_click, and also, the javascript you use to change the control's properties on client side.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Didn't get notified about your update. Don't know if you have solved this problem or not, but after looking at your update, I can see that you are adding div elements. My answer above regards with adding input controls. What you can do is before the page submits or Save button postbacks, use JS to construct a string containing all selected divs necessary values to be used in server-side, save the constructed string into a hidden input control, so that on server-side, you can read the hidden control's value to get all selected divs.